# How to exclude certain orders from the dashboard chart?

Tags: dashboard

I want to exclude orders with a certain attribute set from the chart on the dashboard. I started looking in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph` but somehow I can't find the place. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the abstraction that is added to that part of the admin, it can be indeed a bit tricky to find the actual code which is responsible for loading the orders.

Deeper in the code the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Tab_Orders` block is being loaded. This block will eventually load a helper for fetching data. In this case that is the `Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Dashboard_Order` helper, in which you can find the `_initCollection()` method.

If you extend this helper from your own module, you can adjust the collection filtering to ignore the orders you want to exclude.

If you need more information on how to filter collections, the following link is a great source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento.

Good luck!